# Installing KDE alongside Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, kubuntu, kde

I would like to install KDE alongside Ubuntu 12.04 with following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
```

And then below command get some error :

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

The error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: kde-window-manager
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any helps would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try removing the kubuntu backports repository by going to 
    Software & Updates > Other Sources

And then removing the repository `ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`.

Try again with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Tnx it worked. But why?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, you can accept it as an answer, so others can see that your question is solved. As to the why, something is going wrong with the installation of the dependencies in the backports repository and your system, but it doesn't really matter, you are now on the default installation of kubuntu-desktop and you don't really need to add that repository.